# Failed to remove the header of multiple csv files

Tags: java, csv

I want to remove the header of multiple csv files. So when I am trying to do this it's showing error. But I am able to remove the single csv file's header by this way.

What I have missed to achieve my target that I can remove multiple csv files's header at one shot? I need help on this.

Note: I have given correct filename, directory name, or volume label syntax.

```
    package hadoop;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

class RemoveLine
{

public static void main(String...args) throws IOException 
    {  
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("F://sample1/*.csv", "rw");          
     //Initial write position                                             
    long writePosition = raf.getFilePointer();                            
    raf.readLine();                                                       
    // Shift the next lines upwards.                                      
    long readPosition = raf.getFilePointer();                             

    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];                                         
    int n;                                                                
    while (-1 != (n = raf.read(buff))) {                                  
        raf.seek(writePosition);                                          
        raf.write(buff, 0, n);                                            
        readPosition += n;                                                
        writePosition += n;                                               
        raf.seek(readPosition);                                           
    }                                                                     
    raf.setLength(writePosition);                                         
    raf.close();                                                          
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\sample1\*.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hadoop.RemoveLine.main(RemoveLine.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of glob syntax which you use at the command line. Windows `cmd` and Linux `bash` takes something like `*.csv` and expands it into a list of all the matching file names.

On the other hand, Java's `RandomAccessFile` expect a specific file name and **does not** understand glob syntax. You must implement the behavior yourself. First you need to get a list of all the files which you want to change. Then you have to iterate over that list and perform the actions you want.

Comment: maybe using PathMatcher will do the trick for glob* like syntax https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Comment: I got your point. I have stucked at this point that I have to implement by this way but as per your opinion it's not possible.

Comment: let me try! @YyYo

Comment: @YyYo My answer is intentionally vague on the details of "get a list of all files". There are many, many, many different ways to do this. For example, another solution is to accept command-line arguments. This makes the shell do all the dirty work of expanding `*.csv` to a list of file names. Then you can just iterate over the names directly.